# EJB3 @RunAs annotation and security

Tags: java, security, servlets, ejb

The @RunAs annotation allows to access the bean by specifying role's name only. This is implies that any foreign client able to easily access my bean just pointing the role name, isn't it?

I suppose that the caller and bean locate on different servers.

So what is @RunAs needed for, if it is so easy to falsify the client?
Or how to use this correctly, if i'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit different. See Chapter 9.6 in [WebSphere Application Server V7.0 Security Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247660.html) for more details and examples.

> When a bean calls a method in another bean, the identity of the caller
>   is, by  default, propagated to the next. In this way, all EJB methods
>   in the calling chain  see the same principal if they were to call the
>   getCallerPrincipal() method.
>
> Occasionally, however, it is desirable for one EJB to call another EJB
>   with a  previously defined identity, for instance, one that is a
>   member of a specific role.

The `@RunAs` annotation defines the role that **will be used for delegation**. You can still protect the first bean using `@RolesAllowed`

This `runAsRole` must be mapped to actual user from user registry during application deployment.